# purpose of checkedList method in Collections class

Tags: java, generics

The api says *"Returns a dynamically typesafe view of the specified collection"* 
but still what is the need for it when generics can detect at compile time if anything suspicious is being inserted into a collection.

the doc says *"The generics mechanism in the language provides compile-time (static) type checking, but it is possible to defeat this mechanism with unchecked casts*"

but even this won't work

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Object o = new Float(1.2);
Integer i = (Integer)o; // line3
list.add(i);
```

but even this one wud fail at run time with a `ClassCastException` being thrown at line3 because o actually holds a `Float` , can't convert it to `Integer` . So , I am wondering  how would one even go around static compile-time generic checking to justify the existence of checkedList method

Comment: *"[…] it is possible to defeat this mechanism with **unchecked** casts."* My emphasis in bold. `(Integer)o` is a **checked** cast.

Answer (score 8):

This can be done by not using generics, which could be done if you use a library that was built with a version of Java that doesn't have generics.

The following code is an example of how to do this with generics:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List unsafeList = list; // Cast to a list that is not using generics
Object o = new Float(1.2);
unsafeList.add(o);
// list now contains a non Integer object.
```

This does generate several warnings, but you can of course ignore those if you want.

Comment: Hi, I have one more question if you could please answer, its unrelated to this one, but I am asking here to spare one new post for a minor query  


  `ArrayList.containsAll( list)` is returning me false even though the 2 lists contain the same number of and meaningfully equivalent objects (i.e `equals()` method returns true )   
  I have tested this on a one-to-one object basis in the list. but when I do collectively using `containsAll()` method it returns me false.

Comment: I think you should ask a separate question for this, with a clear reproduction of the steps in them. All I can think of is a bug in the equals implementation where a.equals(b) != b.equals(a).  (or possible a bug in another part of your code).

Comment: hi I have posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29390340/contains-method-in-list-not-working-as-expected)

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the method doesn't make sens when using a checked type list (generics) and
it's ridiculous trying to add a Float when you know your list expects an int.

When the documentation says "*it is possible to defeat this mechanism with unchecked casts.*", it doesn't deal with your obvious not permitted cast. It deals with that code :

```
List list = new ArrayList<>();
Integer i = 3;
Object o = new Float(1.2);
Float f = new Float(2.1);
list.add(i); // warning
list.add(o); // warning
list.add(f); // warning
// list contains [3, 1.2, 2.1]
```

Then, it says "*Usually this is not a problem, as the compiler issues warnings on all such unchecked operations.*", that's why your IDE issues warnings. It's legal, it works but has no sens.

Finally, documentation says that "*...type checking alone is not sufficient. For example, suppose a collection is passed to a third-party library...*" because you can use a type checked collection (to guarantee the type on your side) and pass it to a library that accepts unchecked one. Bad things happens here, the library can do the legal and working bad code we have seen :

```
public class Library {
  public void addNumbers(List list) { // unchecked type
    list.add("5");
    list.add(Duration.ofMinutes(6));
  }
}

public static void main( String[] args ) {
    Library library = new Library();
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(); // checked type
    Integer i1 = 3;
    Integer i2 = 4;
    list.add(i1);
    list.add(i2);
    library.addNumbers(list);
    // list contains [3, 4, 5, PT6M]
}
```

To avoid a third-party adding wrong type values, you must pass it an uncheckedList...

```
public class Library {
  public void addNumbers(List list) {
    list.add("5");
    list.add(Duration.ofMinutes(6));
  }
}
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    Library library = new Library();
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Integer i1 = 3;
    Integer i2 = 4;
    list.add(i1);
    list.add(i2);
    List<Integer> checkedList = Collections.checkedList(list, Integer.class);
    library.addNumbers(checkedList); // ClassCastException
}
```

Notice that if you add value to the checkedList, your initial list will be populated...